# How to get real positions of text glyphs

Tags: macos, glyph, ctfont

CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs returns an array with widths of each text glypth (letter).

How to get real positions for each glyph (letter) in a text string?

If I calculate a sum of all text glyphs a resulting valuer is larger than real text string. This problem is especially actual for certain letters: "To" or "Te".

Comment: There is a much better way to learn the width of a string.

Comment: Advances are not widths; glyph boxes can overlap or have space between them. If you want the width of something, you need to get the width. The advance is the "real position."

Comment: I need to get exact positions of each glypth in a text string. Because I implement a custom text editor with a cursor between letters.